# Node js routing order

Tags: node.js, express

This is my folder structure

```
-build
  -index.html
-server
  -api
   -example1
   -example2
  -routes
   -index.js
-server.js
```

I have `server.js` file as below.

where I have routing defined as below

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));
app.use(require('./server/routes'));
```

In my `server/routes` folder in `index.js` i have routing for different api method

```
router.use('/api/v1/', require('./../api'));
```

what I want is

```
mydomain:port/ --> return index.html
mydomain:port/api/v1/example1 --> return example1 response
mydomain:port/api/v1/example2 --> return example2 response
```

But issue is that when I call `mydomain:port/api/v1/example1` build's index page is always returned.

Comment: What is inside your `api.js` file?

Comment: Have you define route for `*` at the end ? Possible theory, you haven't setup `/api/v1/` correctly, and instead of throwing `404` for `/api/v1/`, it matches with `*` route in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order or use .get instead of .use :

```
router.use("/a", function(req, res, next){ return res.status(200).json({a: "a"})});
router.use("/a/v1", function(req, res, next){ return res.status(200).json({a: "b"})});

// request on /a or /a/v1 will always return a


router.use("/a/v1", function(req, res, next){ return res.status(200).json({a: "b"})});
router.use("/a", function(req, res, next){ return res.status(200).json({a: "a"})});

// work correctly



router.get("/a", function(req, res, next){ return res.status(200).json({a: "a"})});
router.get("/a/v1", function(req, res, next){ return res.status(200).json({a: "b"})});

// work correctly



router.get("/a/v1", function(req, res, next){ return res.status(200).json({a: "b"})});
router.get("/a", function(req, res, next){ return res.status(200).json({a: "a"})});

// work correctly
```

.get, .post, .put, ... use exact route matching

.use use "contains" matching